# Strange MVC issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am having trouble with the following code:

```
@Html.RenderPartial("_SortDisplayPage", new ViewDataDictionary { { "bottomClass", "pagingBottom" } })
```

It gives the error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type void to object
```

I think it's something small but cannot find it...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You want `@Html.Partial` not `RenderPartial`.  RenderPartial writes directly to the response and doesn't return a value.  Partial returns an MvcHtmlString, which the @ operator will write to the response.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works but now I receive a NPE in the partial when I try to access the value passed from the main page: `<div class="paging @ViewData["bottomClass"]">` Do you have a clue for this also?

Comment: Is it possible that you have a case where the bottomClass isn't being set? I don't see how the code you've included would result in that.  To be safe I would probably do something like `@(ViewData["bottomClass"] as string ?? "")`

Comment: +1: Alternatively, OP can use RenderPartial, but must surround it with `@{...;}`

Answer (score 6):

The RenderPartial() call renders its result directly to the response object and cannot be used like a simple string.

All you have to do is enclose the call in a code block.

> @{Html.RenderPartial("TopNavigation");}